# HighStock Depthchart is updating the data strangely

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am using depthchart from highcharts to show data that I am geting via websockets,I want to update the data without refreshing. I tried with `setdata()` and `update()` methods but the data is updated in a strange way

Strange data:

[image: strange data]

the desired result should look like

[image: desired result]

i am geting this when i initialize new depthchart

Comment: Hi @Kiril Stojanovski, Please try to reproduce that situation is some live example (for example jsfiddle). You can use `setTimeout` to simulate getting data from websockets.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this was because I had dynamic (x,y) points and almost on every call the starting point was changing,i solved this by first updating the starting point

```
chart.series[0].update({
          pointStart:updatedPoint,
        })
```

and afterwards

```
chart.series[0].update({
          data:newData,
        })
```